# jqGrid search formated date using toolbar

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

hope somebody can help with a solution to a problem. I have a project where user must be able to set the date format on how he sees the date in jqGrid (which I started to learn recently) and also a toolbar search must be implemented. Right now i have this:

```
       {
            name: 'DueDate',
            formatter: "date",
            formatoptions: {
                srcformat: 'd.m.Y',
                newformat: gridOptions.dateFormat, // setting date format
            },
            sorttype: 'date',
            searchoptions: {
                sopt: ['eq'],
                dataInit: function (e) {
                    //setting jquery-ui extension: multi-datepicker
                }
            }
        },
```

The problem lies in the fact, that one of the possible format choices must be `j.F`, where system shows only date and full month name, but no year. When date format is set to this particular format, toolbar search can't find it, even though I know such a date exists. Formatting itself works well, it is the search for a date that causes problems. Even typing date in toolbar field using this format (any-format actually), doesn't show any results. I might add that by setting `newformat` to any other format, toolbar search works, but not with this `j.F`

System uses jqGrid JS - v5.2.1

P.S. I wonder if it is possible to filter using `d.m.Y` format, while displaying `j.F`

Comment: It is not known where the search is performed - I mean what is the datatype settings - json(xml) or local. If the search is performed at server,  then you should care about what is get from the post. If the datatype is local (or loadonce is true) you should know that the grid store the date field in original format and perform the show of date according to the new format. If a search is performed the newformat is converted back to the original format and a search is performed. If you try with different format on search it will not work.

Comment: Good to know, Tony Tomov. I get data from server and i have loadonce as true, but if I understand you correctly, my problem lies in the fact that it can't transform j.F format back to its original format?

Comment: The question is: What is the value for the newformat (i.e gridOptions.dateFormat) and what value is entered in in the searchtoolbar field?

Comment: gridOptions.dateFormat value is as I mentioned 'j.F' and the value i enter in searchtoolbar field: '8.September'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem:** When the date is formatted from srcformat to the newformat a year is cut-ed according to the rules. When a search date is entered which contain only month and day the year is missing and the search is performed on the original data without year (since the conversion to original date). This causes the wrong searching results. Example if you enter 4.July as search string then according to the rules this string is converted to 4.7.1970 and search is performed to this date, which give not the desired results.

**The solution:** One possible solution is to define a virtual field which contain the formatted data and when a search is performed it should be applied not the the actual date field, but to the new build-ed virtual field. Below is the code:

```
{
    name: 'DueDate',
    index : 'mydate',
    formatter: "date",
    formatoptions: {
        srcformat: 'd.m.Y',
        newformat: gridOptions.dateFormat, // setting date format
    },
    sorttype: 'date',
    searchoptions: {
        sopt: ['eq'],
        dataInit: function (e) {
            //setting jquery-ui extension: multi-datepicker
        }
    }
},
{
    name : 'mydate',
    hidden: true,
    jsonmap : function(item) {
        return  $.jgrid.parseDate.call($("#jqGrid")[0] , 'd.m.Y', item.DueDate , 'j.F'); 
    }
},
```

Note the index property in DueDate. The #jqGrid is the id of the grid in definition in jsonmap in mydate  virtual field

Comment: Thanks Tony, you are a life saver. It worked, and now i can finaly move on