# jQGrid DateFilter not working after using custom date format

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

Hi I am using jqGrid and my date src format is like Feb 27, 2018 7:22:43 PM
So I have formatted it like

```js
formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'M d, Y g:i:s A', newformat: 'm/d/Y'}
```

Now, the filter is not working only for month
I tried to add sorttype: 'date' option but after adding it filter stopped working for year and day as well.

I think I might have missed something in the formatoptions that is causing this
Please advice.

I have done some changes 
Below is the updated code 
Please have a look.

```js
{
        label: '<font size="2">SSC Support Approved Through Date</font>', 
        name:'supportApprovedThroughDate',
        index:'myDate',
  editable: true,formatter: 'date',
  sorttype: 'date',
  formatoptions: { srcformat: 'M d, Y g:i:s A', newformat: 'm/d/Y'},
  searchoptions: { 
                        sopt: ['eq'],
                        placeholder:'Filter By Approved Through  Date',
                        title:'Filter By Approved Through Date'
                       }
  },
  {
       name : 'myDate',
    hidden: true,
    jsonmap : function(item) {
     console.log(item);// Not getting printed.
     return  $.jgrid.parseDate.call($("#jqGrid")[0] , 'M d, Y g:i:s A', item.supportApprovedThroughDate , 'm/d/Y'); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used - Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or jqGrid <=4.7?

Comment: We are using jqGrid  5.0.1  

http://guriddo.net

Comment: Please look [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547993/jqgrid-search-formated-date-using-toolbar/48590469#48590469), where the problem is similar and you will need to adjust to your needs

Comment: Hi Tony I have tried as per the link but it's still not working if possible can you please have a look into code snippet in question

Comment: The above code work only if the datatype is **local** or the **loadonce** parameter is true.  If the datatype parameter is not local and you use server side paging and searching you will need to have logic in your server to make the right searching on the date. In all other cases we need working example of the problem

Comment: Yes I have checked that the datatype is local and table div id is also jqGrid 
I think the function in jsonmap property is not getting called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of pure datatype local (i.e when loadonce is not used) we need to to add additionally a field myDate in the **data**  in order to make this happen. In my case I use onInitGrid, but you can  use any operation before to load the data in the grid.

Code and example link below:

```
var myData = [
  {
   id: 1,
   name: "aaz",
   supportApprovedThroughDate : 'Feb 27, 2018 7:22:43 PM'
  }, 
  {
   id: 2,
   name: "bbz",
   supportApprovedThroughDate : 'Feb 19, 2018 7:22:43 PM'
  },
  {
   id: 3,
   name: "ccz",
   supportApprovedThroughDate : 'Feb 27, 2018 7:22:43 PM'
  } 
];

$.jgrid.defaults.width = 600;
$.jgrid.defaults.responsive = true;


$("#gMain").jqGrid({
    data: myData,    
    datatype: "local",
    colModel: [{
        name: "id",
        index: "id",        
        width:80,
        editable:true
    },{
        name: "name",
        index: "name",
        searchoptions:{clearSearch:false},
        width:100,
        editable:true
    },{
        label: 'SSC Support', 
        name:'supportApprovedThroughDate',
        index:'myDate',
            editable: true,
          formatter: 'date',
            sorttype: 'date',
            formatoptions: { srcformat: 'M d, Y g:i:s A', newformat: 'm/d/Y'},
        searchoptions: { 
            sopt: ['eq'],
            placeholder:'Filter By Approved Through  Date',
            title:'Filter By Approved Through Date'
        }
    },{
            name : 'myDate',
              hidden: true,
              formatter : 'date',
        formatoptions : { srcformat:'m/d/Y', newformat : 'm/d/Y'}
    }],
    caption: "Test JqGrid",
    pager: '#pMain',
    search: true,
    shrinkToFit: false,    
    forceFit:false,
    autowidth:true, 
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30,50,100],
    onInitGrid : function() {
        for(var i=0, len=this.p.data.length; i<len;i++) {
            var row = this.p.data[i];
            row['myDate'] = $.jgrid.parseDate.call(this , 'M d, Y g:i:s A', row.supportApprovedThroughDate , 'm/d/Y');
        }
    }
});

$("#gMain").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
    stringResult: true, 
    searchOnEnter: true,                                                                                 
    defaultSearch: 'cn'
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/guriddo/e4o1f961/29/) with exactly  your settings